# showing first is real value but second shows undefined in my modal project

Tags: node.js, ajax, bootstrap-modal

my modal code

```
  <form action="/update" method="post">
      <div class="modal fade" id="duzen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <h5 class="modal-title" id="Moda1">Etiketi Düzenle</h5>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" name="okuyucu" class="form-control okuyucu" placeholder="okuyucu" required>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" name="x" class="form-control x" placeholder="x" required>
             </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" name="y" class="form-control y" placeholder="y" required>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <input type="hidden" name="idnew_table" class="idnew_table">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-pill" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-pill">Güncelle</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

my ajax code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {
 var x1="";
  var y1="";
  var okuyucu1="";
  var id="";
$.ajax({

 
    url: "http://localhost:10001/etiketokuyucu", 
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
     
        if(response.length > 0){
            for(let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
                var newRow = $("<tr>");
                var cols = "";
                var okuyucu = '';
                var x = '';
                var y = '';
                var id='';
                cols += '<td>' + response[index].idnew_table+'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response[index].okuyucu +'</td>' ;
                cols += '<td> '+ response[index].x +'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response[index].y +'</td>'; 
             cols += '<td>' 
              +
                              '<div class="dropdown d-inline-block widget-dropdown">'+
                                '<a class="dropdown-toggle icon-burger-mini" href="" role="button" id="dropdown-recent-order1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static"></a>'+
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdown-recent-order1">'+
                                 '<li class="dropdown-item edit">'+
                                    '<a href="#duzen" class= "edit" data-idnew_table='+response[index].idnew_table + ' data-okuyucu=' +response[index].okuyucu + ' data-x= ' + response[index].x + ' data-y= ' + response[index].y + ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#duzen">Düzenle</a>'+
                                  '</li>'+
                                  '<li class="dropdown-item delete">'+
                                    '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Sil</a>'+
                                  '</li>'+
                                '</ul>'+
                              '</div>'+
                            '</td>' ;        
                newRow.append(cols);
                $("#example .tbody").append(newRow);
            }  

        }
    }
})
})
```

my modal script code

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //showing data to modal for edit record
        $('#example').on('click','.edit',function(){
         
          var idnew_table = $(this).data('idnew_table');
          
          var okuyucu= $(this).data('okuyucu');
          var x = $(this).data('x');
          var y = $(this).data('y');
          console.log(idnew_table+"okuyucu="+okuyucu + "x=" +x+" y="+y);
          
    
          var modal = $(this);
           
            modal.find('#okuyucu').text(okuyucu);
            modal.find('#x').text(x);
            modal.find('#y').text(y);
          
          
          
          /*$('#duzen').modal('show');
          $('.okuyucu').val($(this).data('okuyucu'))
          $('.x').val(x);
          $('.y').val(y);
          $('.idnew_table').val(idnew_table);
        */ });
        //showing modal for delete record
        
      });
```

I want to show my mysql data on modal but ı got an error.In this code first show true value in console okuyucu,x,y etc but in modal shows they are undefined.why are they not show true value in my console when they second run?It passes data from ajax to table and I read that value from script code but doesn't show in my modal

Thank you  for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code for appending value to table was having `2` class `edit` i.e : `li` and `<a>` so when you click on edit link both class where getting called and it was returning undefined .Also , your input inside modal doesn't have any `id` instead it only have `name`i have corrected your code .

**Demo Code** :

```js
//demo data
var response = [{
  "idnew_table": "1",
  "okuyucu": "abc",
  "x": "12",
  "y": "fbg"
}, {
  "idnew_table": "2",
  "okuyucu": "abcd",
  "x": "152",
  "y": "f5bg"
}, {
  "idnew_table": "3",
  "okuyucu": "abce",
  "x": "125",
  "y": "fb5g"
}]
if (response.length > 0) {
  for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    var okuyucu = '';
    var x = '';
    var y = '';
    var id = '';
    cols += '<td>' + response[index].idnew_table + '</td>';
    cols += '<td> ' + response[index].okuyucu + '</td>';
    cols += '<td> ' + response[index].x + '</td>';
    cols += '<td> ' + response[index].y + '</td>';
    cols += '<td>' +
      '<div class="dropdown d-inline-block widget-dropdown">' +
      '<a class="dropdown-toggle icon-burger-mini" href="" role="button" id="dropdown-recent-order1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static"></a>' +
      '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdown-recent-order1">' +
      '<li class="dropdown-item ">' + //<--remove class edit
     '<a href="#duzen" class= "edit" data-idnew_table='+response[index].idnew_table + ' data-okuyucu=' +response[index].okuyucu + ' data-x= ' + response[index].x + ' data-y= ' + response[index].y + ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#duzen">Düzenle</a>'+
                                 
      '</li>' +
      '<li class="dropdown-item delete">' +
      '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Sil</a>' +
      '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#example .tbody").append(newRow);
  }

}


//showing data to modal for edit record
 $('#example').on('click','.edit',function(){

  var idnew_table = $(this).data('idnew_table');

  var okuyucu = $(this).data('okuyucu');
  var x = $(this).data('x');
  var y = $(this).data('y');
  console.log(idnew_table + "okuyucu=" + okuyucu + "x=" + x + " y=" + y);

//find input under modal and set value of inputs
  $("#duzen").find('input[name=okuyucu]').val(okuyucu);
  $("#duzen").find('input[name=x]').val(x);
  $("#duzen").find('input[name=y]').val(y);
  $('#duzen').modal('show');


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="example" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>idnew_table</th>
    <th>okuyucu</th>
    <th>x</th>
    <th>y</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">
  </tbody>

</table>

<form action="/update" method="post">
  <div class="modal fade" id="duzen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="Moda1">Etiketi Düzenle</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="okuyucu" class="form-control okuyucu" placeholder="okuyucu" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="x" class="form-control x" placeholder="x" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="y" class="form-control y" placeholder="y" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="hidden" name="idnew_table" class="idnew_table">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-pill" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-pill">Güncelle</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```